# Why does this SassError occur?

Tags: css, sass

This is the alert.scss file

```
@mixin alert-variant($background, $border, $color) {
  color: $color;
  @include gradient-bg($background);
  border-color: $border;

  hr {
    border-top-color: darken($border, 5%);
  }

  .alert-link {
    color: darken($color, 10%);
  }
}
```

it retuns this error :

> SassError: $color: null is not a color.
>
> color: darken($color, 10%);

I tried setting default values for $color such as white or #000 , but it didn't work.

Comment: How are you using this mixin??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mixin is ok, this is example how to use it in your code:

```
.foobar {
    @include alert-variant(red, green, blue);
}

or:

.foobar {
    @include alert-variant(#ff0000, #ff00ff, #ffffff);
}
```

If you want default color for that mixin:

```
@mixin alert-variant($background, $border, $color: #000) { ... }

and in your code:

.foobar {
    @include alert-variant(red, green);
}
```